# file upload in multiple directory

Tags: php

This is a script that Upload a file in all directory. But when i run it, its only upload One time and then fail to upload . whats wrong in this code ?

```
function read_directory($p_pathname)
{
$d = dir ($p_pathname);
$target = $p_pathname; 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'])) 
{
    echo $target. "Done<br>";
} 
else 
{
    echo $target."Sorry<br>";
}
while (($file = $d->read()) !== false)
{
    if (($file != ".") and ($file != ".."))
    {
        $filetype = filetype ("{$d->path}/{$file}");

        if ($filetype == "dir")
        {
            read_directory ("{$d->path}/{$file}");
        }
        else
        {
            // echo "\tFILE: {$d->path}/{$file}\n";
        }
    }
}
$d->close;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `copy()` instead of `move_uploaded_file()`. `move_uploaded_file()` deletes the source file when it's done, so you can't use it multiple times on the same file. `copy()` leaves the original file alone, so you can do it as many times as you want.

When the script exits, PHP automatically removes the temp file that was uploaded if it doesn't get moved by the script.

Answer (score 0):

in the first time your moving the file... not copying ... so only next time that file not in the temp directory, so you can't move again..